# Getting file from MaterialUI Upload Button to React Hook and uploading to Firestorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, firebase-storage

Hey guys I am using MaterialUI's Upload Button from here: https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/

As you can see below I have copy pasted that button and now I want to upload it to Firebase Firestorage using my hook. By pressing on the button it class changeFoto

```
  <input
            accept="image/*"
            className={classes.input}
            id="contained-button-file"
            multiple
            type="file"
            onChange={(e) => changeFoto(e)}
          />
          <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
            <Button className={classes.fotoButton} component="span">
              Foto
            </Button>
          </label>
```

Here you can see the changeFoto function:

(setFoto is a hook in this case and foto the variable of the useState)

```
const changeFoto = (e) => {
    setFoto(e.target.files[0]);
    const pflegeengelRef = storage.child(
      "pflegeengel/" + pflegeengelDocumentIDs[selectedIndex]
    );
    pflegeengelRef.put(foto).then(function (snapshot) {
      console.log("Uploaded a file!");
    });
  };
```

And indeed something gets uploaded when I go look into the storage there is a file. But it is not my image file it was some weird file format that only had the text "undefined" in it. So that is my problem I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `setFoto` is an async function. It doesn't update `foto` immediately - it triggers a render with the new `foto` as the new value.

When you try to upload `foto`, it hasn't updated yet. Using `put(e.target.files[0])` would solve your problem.